# Возврат к текущему шагу цикла, после обработки в нём исключения

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения

Допустим, у меня есть вот такой цикл, в котором N-шагов и на каждый шаг приходится K-действий.

```
numbers = [1, 0, 3]

for number in numbers:
        try:
            print('1 act.:', number - 1)
            print('2 act.:', number / number)
            print('3 act.:', number+ 1)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("2 act.: None")
```

Результат:

```
Step 1      | Step 2        |   Step 3
____________|_______________|_______________
1 act.: 0   | 1 act.: -1    | 1 act.: 2
2 act.: 1.0 | 2 act.: None  | 2 act.: 1.0
3 act.: 2   |               | 3 act.: 4
```

На Step 2, во втором действие возникает исключение, мы его перехватываем, но после этого переходим к Step 3, минуя третье действие у Step 2.

Нужно после исключения, вернуться к исполнению следующего действия в шаге.
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы слишком большой участок кода обернули в исключение. В вашем случае следует сделать так:

```
for number in numbers:
    print('1 act.:', number - 1)
    try:
        print('2 act.:', number / number)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("2 act.: None")
    print('3 act.:', number+ 1)
```

Comment: Да, я так бы и сделал, но допустим, у меня в шаге цикла каждое действие может вызвать исключение, да и их количество весьма незаурядное. Оборачивать каждое — лениво :) Впрочем, как и лениво обработать данные, вызывающие исключение в цикле, еще до его запуска. И решил я из двух зол, выбрать тупиковую...